# How can I add a vertical scrollbar to a sidebar of links using Flexbox and no set heights?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to achieve a layout with HTML/CSS that has a header with no set height, and a sidebar and content area next to each other below the header that take up the remaining height of the screen. In addition, the sidebar often has so many links that the links scroll off the screen, but instead of that happening, I would like to add a vertical scrollbar to just the sidebar section, and not have there be a scrollbar for the entire page.

I've been trying everything I can think of and find online, but nothing seems to be working. Here's some basic HTML/CSS to demonstrate the layout and the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body,
            div,
            h1,
            html,
            li,
            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            h1 {
                line-height: 1;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            .header {
                background: #CC76CC;
                padding: 40px 20px;
            }

            .sidebar-and-content {
                display: flex;
                flex: 1;
            }

            .sidebar {
                background: #DDD;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-shrink: 0;
                width: 225px;
            }

            .nav-links-container {
                flex: 1;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            .nav-links li {
                border-bottom: #999 solid 1px;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .content {
                background: #FFFF91;
                flex: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-and-content">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="nav-links-container">
                        <ul class="nav-links">
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any good ideas and/or know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body,
            div,
            h1,
            html,
            li,
            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            h1 {
                line-height: 1;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height:100vh;
            }

            .header {
                background: #CC76CC;
                padding: 40px 20px;
            }

            .sidebar-and-content {
                display: flex;
                flex: 1;
              height:1px ;
            }

            .sidebar {
                background: #DDD;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-shrink: 0;
                width: 225px;
            }

            .nav-links-container {
                flex: 1;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .nav-links li {
                border-bottom: #999 solid 1px;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .content {
                background: #FFFF91;
                flex: 1;
              overflow :auto ;
            }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-and-content">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="nav-links-container">
                        <ul class="nav-links">
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                            <li>Link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut semper porta ante, sit amet euismod ipsum venenatis vitae. Mauris ut tristique nibh, a ultricies nulla. Nullam fermentum eu mi ac cursus. Integer semper suscipit ex eu mattis. Phasellus iaculis ultricies ornare. Suspendisse ut nisi diam. Nunc pellentesque lacinia turpis vehicula pharetra. Aenean aliquam cursus elit nec fermentum. Morbi sed tempor nunc. In efficitur arcu ut finibus ultricies.

Suspendisse cursus semper semper. Praesent elit metus, venenatis vitae dictum eu, viverra ut tellus. Vestibulum ornare dui sit amet enim consectetur ornare. Cras porttitor nisl ultrices erat laoreet, ut ultricies quam condimentum. Duis a magna quis mi consequat facilisis id id dui. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer suscipit odio nibh, quis fermentum tellus hendrerit et.

Nam et euismod eros, id porttitor velit. Ut eget porttitor nibh, non interdum magna. Donec facilisis quis orci pharetra semper. Curabitur hendrerit massa interdum lacinia cursus. Aenean rutrum, lectus non efficitur sodales, sem lacus volutpat lectus, sed pharetra nisl metus in tortor. Integer eu turpis turpis. Phasellus eu placerat metus. Aenean ac massa consequat, consequat erat non, sollicitudin mi. Vivamus porttitor mattis accumsan.

Duis justo elit, finibus quis hendrerit at, ultricies quis nulla. Donec lobortis orci libero, eget dictum ipsum cursus ut. Phasellus vitae pellentesque risus. Mauris et dictum eros. Donec consectetur erat odio, nec semper nibh lacinia ac. Vestibulum rutrum laoreet rhoncus. Fusce dictum ut dui a fermentum. Donec hendrerit volutpat elit non ornare. Curabitur at neque semper, blandit lorem et, varius eros. Suspendisse nec turpis nec diam gravida pharetra.

Morbi turpis nulla, feugiat et egestas in, tempor sit amet ipsum. Nam ac arcu aliquet, congue ipsum ut, lacinia velit. Nulla neque nulla, vulputate in ex nec, laoreet gravida enim. Sed finibus turpis quis dapibus tincidunt. Phasellus elementum tincidunt neque sed porta. Etiam non finibus libero, vitae ullamcorper erat. Nullam lobortis eget diam eget vestibulum. In non dolor sed mauris finibus tempus non et justo. Nam convallis nec elit quis tempor. Vivamus ultricies pellentesque lectus nec commodo. Sed et molestie lacus, non gravida enim. Vivamus feugiat tempus ipsum ac eleifend. Nulla id mi tempor, tincidunt justo fermentum, convallis orci.

Fusce finibus placerat sapien at luctus. Mauris non velit diam. Vestibulum vel porta tellus, aliquet vulputate mi. Aenean a turpis ac urna gravida porta et sit amet ante. Phasellus vehicula feugiat leo ut faucibus. Curabitur porta, leo id auctor viverra, lorem nulla maximus turpis, eu laoreet leo risus id urna. Nullam finibus lectus ante, eget ultrices velit tempor ut. Maecenas quis tincidunt tortor. Nam eu facilisis libero. Morbi fermentum dolor sit amet lorem dictum aliquet. Curabitur porta nisl sed velit facilisis rhoncus. Duis eu eros quis metus blandit efficitur. Aenean venenatis est ante. Vestibulum quis laoreet dolor, sed bibendum metus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras feugiat, dui vel lacinia scelerisque, lacus urna tempor quam, sit amet iaculis diam nulla et felis.

Curabitur ac accumsan arcu. Donec at euismod nisi, sit amet interdum sapien. Phasellus efficitur, felis ut condimentum accumsan, tortor ipsum convallis massa, ac iaculis quam metus quis nulla. Fusce vel turpis porta, tempor ex non, eleifend ante. Etiam nibh erat, interdum eget commodo nec, interdum eu orci. Vivamus eleifend nunc sed neque cursus pretium. Vestibulum non nisl eros. Fusce cursus tristique eros a finibus. Mauris vel massa tempor, vestibulum lorem in, bibendum urna. Donec cursus dolor nunc, sed lobortis tellus scelerisque ut. Nunc venenatis tincidunt neque eu gravida. Vestibulum quis ante eu velit interdum vulputate.

Vivamus sit amet mollis justo. Quisque sit amet molestie libero. Nam ut tempor dui, a commodo tortor. Quisque vehicula congue maximus. Proin dignissim ante nisl, eget ullamcorper lorem vestibulum sed. Vestibulum commodo porttitor vulputate. Sed augue ante, hendrerit et tincidunt maximus, pretium et tellus. Morbi et tortor eu nisl dignissim pulvinar. Morbi dignissim dictum metus vel lobortis. In sit amet tellus sit amet dui auctor tincidunt ac in nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce id metus lacinia, cursus ex in, gravida nibh. Ut mollis mi at urna gravida, in sagittis sem dictum. Nullam pretium dolor mauris, eget lobortis libero euismod a. Maecenas aliquet dolor dolor, cursus malesuada erat ornare ac.

Pellentesque ultrices semper tortor non fermentum. Fusce pellentesque fermentum justo eu placerat. Donec tincidunt dolor id nunc vehicula mattis. Suspendisse fermentum libero vel est sollicitudin, non interdum urna placerat. Cras dignissim nibh id tincidunt pellentesque. Quisque ac cursus enim. Phasellus pretium varius aliquam. Mauris arcu enim, posuere sit amet est eu, vestibulum euismod sapien. Etiam sed velit consequat, dictum turpis eu, vehicula orci. Morbi tincidunt sit amet erat in mattis. Curabitur ac nisi sit amet ipsum ultrices tempus vel et est. Vivamus ornare dolor vel ligula ultrices tempor.

Nunc id ultrices sapien. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque tempus cursus tellus, quis ultricies neque commodo ut. Integer bibendum orci vitae metus fringilla, quis tristique dui iaculis. Vestibulum eu velit et leo facilisis rhoncus sit amet at tortor. Morbi dignissim ante ut neque lacinia dictum. In vel risus at ex lobortis laoreet et nec leo. Mauris rutrum orci sollicitudin ex rhoncus ultrices.

Nunc dapibus pulvinar ex sed sollicitudin. Donec nec luctus tortor. Phasellus porta, ipsum sit amet sagittis sagittis, lectus sem vestibulum enim, et placerat velit diam sit amet leo. Curabitur turpis mi, eleifend eu porttitor mattis, aliquam sed ipsum. Pellentesque gravida condimentum sem, id laoreet erat vulputate in. Nulla facilisi. Mauris in eros vel sapien accumsan viverra eget sed est. Ut arcu orci, accumsan faucibus ipsum ut, accumsan luctus eros. Proin eget dui aliquam, dictum elit in, malesuada odio. Sed non arcu molestie, dignissim odio ut, sagittis neque. Duis sit amet quam massa. Mauris tempor, eros a placerat ornare, odio dui dapibus orci, quis feugiat libero neque posuere quam. Sed gravida velit purus, ut laoreet tortor mollis sit amet. Aliquam rutrum non lorem nec interdum. Pellentesque ornare blandit mattis.

Aliquam non commodo felis. Maecenas scelerisque elementum arcu, at tincidunt elit fringilla et. Nam ut felis dapibus elit accumsan sollicitudin id at ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque tincidunt mi interdum dui porta, ut tristique nibh auctor. Vestibulum in aliquam quam. Ut suscipit fringilla tellus, et elementum ligula finibus id. Curabitur auctor tincidunt finibus.

Donec sit amet orci pharetra, tempor orci in, placerat felis. Cras aliquam augue a lacus molestie, efficitur ultrices odio porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eleifend arcu quis eros ultricies lobortis. Curabitur dignissim mi id feugiat finibus. In eu sodales sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;

Sed nec auctor velit. Vivamus pellentesque eget risus eu luctus. Etiam ac odio vitae quam semper vulputate quis non nulla. Pellentesque eget luctus turpis, quis volutpat tellus. Sed commodo accumsan magna ut dignissim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut congue, magna id sagittis cursus, neque risus ultricies libero, et posuere est est ac mi. Donec quam urna, lobortis nec nibh convallis, auctor vehicula augue. Vestibulum turpis massa, placerat ut felis sit amet, maximus malesuada turpis. Integer scelerisque nisl sagittis, tempor quam vitae, feugiat tellus.

Phasellus efficitur, risus eget suscipit rhoncus, enim enim tempor elit, id tempor nibh metus vel elit. Suspendisse mattis lacinia sollicitudin. In urna dolor, eleifend a cursus ac, varius a lectus. Phasellus vestibulum, libero id congue venenatis, risus leo fringilla odio, ac dapibus augue enim vestibulum mauris. Nulla sit amet dignissim sem. Sed convallis eros non neque laoreet mollis. Sed at ex ligula. Vivamus luctus, urna nec fringilla faucibus, nisl est accumsan quam, eget gravida nisl odio at sem. In lacinia, diam ut faucibus pellentesque, mi ligula elementum est, et porta mauris tellus sit amet eros.

Donec luctus quis dui vel ornare. Vestibulum feugiat enim et semper tempor. Nullam dictum pellentesque orci. Aenean eleifend dolor at condimentum tincidunt. Sed molestie felis vel ipsum ullamcorper vulputate. Donec vel urna ac mi consectetur imperdiet eget eu arcu. Curabitur elit ante, sollicitudin vel convallis sed, molestie id justo. Vivamus lacinia risus eu mi suscipit gravida. Ut vitae ex pulvinar, rhoncus erat non, efficitur purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec est velit, ultricies a lacinia sed, faucibus ut erat. Nullam ut mi tincidunt, porttitor lacus sed, euismod velit. Nunc scelerisque lacus a lectus eleifend, tempus mollis urna rutrum.

Nam eget lobortis nisl. Pellentesque sed venenatis elit. In auctor volutpat posuere. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut cursus nunc augue, ac egestas tellus iaculis eu. Vivamus ultrices cursus mauris, ac bibendum eros accumsan eu. Aliquam id tincidunt purus. Sed sodales consectetur odio porttitor pulvinar. Donec sodales mattis sem, id elementum leo ornare at. Aenean blandit id magna a placerat.

Suspendisse quis tincidunt leo. Maecenas sapien massa, consequat at pharetra et, sodales vel velit. Ut convallis volutpat nibh id eleifend. Vestibulum molestie mauris ac ornare fringilla. Aliquam ipsum felis, fermentum eu lacinia nec, faucibus at nunc. Donec imperdiet, turpis non consectetur sodales, orci dolor ultricies magna, quis porttitor massa ligula ultrices magna. Vivamus auctor neque eros, nec dictum nulla vestibulum non. Pellentesque luctus, urna nec imperdiet maximus, nisi nibh suscipit ipsum, eget luctus leo ex quis lorem. Praesent in ex vitae urna laoreet imperdiet. Phasellus pulvinar ipsum vitae dui ultrices suscipit. Aenean est ipsum, ornare eget porta sit amet, tincidunt sed dui. Nam et urna porttitor, tempor magna ac, semper nisi. Vestibulum nisl purus, laoreet non ex a, ultricies finibus dolor.

Maecenas id sapien semper, luctus ante in, aliquet mi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in odio magna. Aliquam pulvinar euismod ligula eu imperdiet. Integer condimentum nulla magna, feugiat ullamcorper ipsum dictum ac. Suspendisse id tempor neque, vitae blandit urna. Fusce eget tempus erat. Sed sit amet elit vitae nisl maximus dictum eget et nisl. In egestas at leo sed lacinia. Pellentesque at hendrerit neque, quis pharetra nunc. Donec dignissim erat in libero porttitor cursus.

Maecenas pellentesque tempus dapibus. Aenean sodales interdum dolor, sed iaculis erat luctus ac. Morbi interdum feugiat nisi, sed eleifend quam vehicula a. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed malesuada arcu sed lectus placerat, eget blandit purus luctus. Cras tristique ligula neque. Vestibulum finibus nunc ac ex ultricies, eget aliquam leo iaculis. Duis vestibulum imperdiet eros in vulputate. In ex odio, dictum aliquet dui at, elementum ultricies justo. Ut pulvinar condimentum dui, tincidunt faucibus nunc tempor at.

Quisque eleifend diam a lorem euismod, vitae dictum eros euismod. Pellentesque sed vehicula ante, ut laoreet libero. Suspendisse eget massa sollicitudin tortor viverra ultrices id vitae lorem. Donec sagittis nunc ut hendrerit lacinia. Donec elementum tellus efficitur felis cursus mollis. Etiam quis erat massa. Nullam eu dui felis. Suspendisse pulvinar leo augue, vel fermentum ex feugiat sed.

Morbi sagittis fermentum massa, vitae dictum orci. Aliquam fringilla, elit at condimentum congue, lacus libero porttitor urna, vel efficitur ante ante pulvinar risus. Aenean non enim nulla. Nullam eget elit ut lorem tincidunt malesuada. Curabitur dapibus eros molestie felis commodo tristique. Quisque non mi in nunc ultrices malesuada at ut dolor. Nullam metus mauris, aliquam id accumsan ac, efficitur ut felis. Ut purus lacus, consectetur quis dolor a, sagittis luctus est. Praesent tristique interdum sapien ut scelerisque. Proin nisi sem, luctus eu massa vitae, tincidunt tristique urna. Phasellus a nibh ut magna pretium convallis eget non justo. Ut id arcu sit amet nisi sollicitudin convallis sed sed dolor. Proin fermentum non ex et volutpat. Donec vitae erat rutrum, laoreet dui at, egestas arcu.

Etiam lobortis sodales mollis. Maecenas nec neque malesuada est ullamcorper venenatis eget ut lacus. Suspendisse maximus pretium tincidunt. Etiam a auctor mi. Morbi sollicitudin metus nec dolor porttitor, ac placerat arcu tempus. Sed turpis mi, cursus sit amet egestas ac, consequat sit amet nulla. Suspendisse dapibus malesuada blandit. Donec aliquet ligula urna, vel venenatis nibh facilisis sed.

Fusce volutpat ex et leo sagittis, eu posuere sapien scelerisque. Proin eget nisi sed metus accumsan suscipit in id leo. Quisque ac rutrum velit. Nulla id convallis libero. Duis euismod feugiat sodales. Aenean placerat, est nec convallis luctus, massa leo finibus nunc, in viverra dolor nunc at arcu. Cras lobortis rutrum vestibulum. Integer pellentesque placerat sapien non mattis. Maecenas in velit mi. Cras finibus in felis nec ullamcorper. Aenean ut est et felis elementum efficitur at vitae lacus. Maecenas aliquam dapibus massa, et semper lacus vulputate et.

In imperdiet convallis tellus ut semper. Quisque placerat eros id condimentum faucibus. Nulla et faucibus elit. Nunc tincidunt risus eget velit cursus semper. Etiam viverra nibh eget turpis gravida ultrices. Cras eget iaculis tortor, vehicula consequat est. Pellentesque blandit nisl id neque ultrices, in tempus quam facilisis.

Aenean feugiat felis sed ligula tincidunt suscipit a elementum dui. Phasellus laoreet lorem sit amet nisi varius, sit amet tincidunt augue dictum. Ut dictum ipsum finibus, pellentesque odio vel, accumsan odio. Proin porttitor risus lectus, commodo tristique diam commodo et. Integer ornare vel dui sit amet placerat. Quisque tellus purus, pharetra eget mi sit amet, faucibus imperdiet dui. Aliquam malesuada sapien eu enim laoreet, nec blandit lacus pulvinar. Ut in diam condimentum, iaculis mauris eget, venenatis ipsum. Donec finibus diam arcu, sit amet laoreet leo consectetur in. Duis erat turpis, consequat sed ornare sit amet, feugiat ac purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis elit lacus, commodo id leo sed, congue consequat lectus.

Mauris facilisis et ligula id faucibus. Nunc non lobortis metus, tristique finibus tortor. Fusce interdum interdum felis elementum dignissim. Vivamus diam nisi, dictum dapibus consectetur ut, laoreet vel est. Vivamus posuere consectetur dui, in vehicula felis interdum nec. Pellentesque tincidunt magna turpis, a vehicula ante pellentesque sit amet. Nullam id feugiat nisl, eu blandit felis.

Suspendisse consequat enim at enim sagittis, sed feugiat tellus iaculis. Vestibulum volutpat dignissim porttitor. Vivamus at ante nec augue tempus laoreet. In volutpat risus at ipsum gravida tempus. Sed et vulputate dui. Praesent eget tempus mauris. Vivamus congue tellus at lacus sollicitudin luctus vitae quis est. Vivamus interdum nisi ut neque mattis, a suscipit lacus tempor. Vestibulum tellus orci, scelerisque sodales metus eu, cursus aliquam elit. Nunc porta fringilla turpis, ac varius arcu blandit ac. Nulla ornare ligula non tortor hendrerit dictum.

Aliquam lobortis, lectus sit amet blandit pulvinar, risus quam condimentum diam, convallis tristique lacus est non mi. Sed eu felis purus. Sed velit justo, posuere eget porttitor eget, vehicula vel neque. Suspendisse malesuada, nunc nec auctor cursus, lorem dolor rutrum dolor, ut scelerisque nibh nisi sed justo. Nullam ac orci non nisl varius porttitor. Vestibulum non lorem at mauris malesuada interdum vel quis dolor. Pellentesque porttitor erat vel sem venenatis feugiat eget vitae nisi. Sed tempus urna vitae egestas consequat. Curabitur vitae porttitor erat. In augue sem, sodales eget velit ut, pulvinar consectetur sem. Mauris rutrum erat vitae placerat egestas. Ut est odio, semper ut augue et, luctus sagittis risus. Curabitur ex est, ultrices nec neque consequat, dapibus malesuada magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ipsum turpis, ultricies vitae tortor nec, malesuada sagittis orci.

Cras consequat mi odio. Proin vestibulum vestibulum efficitur. Ut et neque sapien. In sit amet ipsum in sapien molestie auctor ut eu diam. Aenean ornare erat ut felis faucibus, quis laoreet dui pretium. Praesent porttitor imperdiet mauris, eget consequat lectus lacinia a. Nam maximus eleifend velit, ut ultrices orci finibus nec. Donec id sapien ut erat fermentum vulputate in vel risus. Fusce neque ante, semper at euismod in, mollis sit amet neque. Fusce gravida pretium sapien, a eleifend nisi euismod sit amet. Vestibulum vulputate dapibus dolor non tempor. Proin eros velit, ornare vel ultrices non, faucibus at diam. Praesent pretium tempor arcu. Cras semper pellentesque commodo. Cras nec urna in tortor molestie varius in vitae odio. Ut finibus lacus ut est tristique suscipit.

Donec interdum magna urna, vel posuere nisi pellentesque sed. Nam quis mi sit amet quam laoreet eleifend. Aenean quis tellus non nulla auctor fringilla. Nunc felis arcu, volutpat quis porta vel, molestie at massa. Morbi vitae enim urna. Etiam euismod facilisis leo, vel dignissim nisi tempus sit amet. Aliquam aliquam cursus nibh, faucibus pharetra quam.

Maecenas luctus, velit ac malesuada egestas, leo nunc elementum neque, at porttitor ligula augue in odio. Sed tempus egestas dui, vitae varius metus volutpat id. Aliquam ornare, lacus posuere sollicitudin vehicula, felis diam consequat arcu, a laoreet nulla erat non nisl. Proin cursus ut tellus at condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin finibus enim et faucibus dignissim. Donec non ex vulputate, interdum orci ut, dignissim urna. Nulla rhoncus sollicitudin congue. Mauris semper arcu a massa malesuada scelerisque. Quisque ligula metus, condimentum nec interdum eget, efficitur in nunc.

Phasellus vel luctus dui, quis ornare orci. Etiam sollicitudin, neque at venenatis luctus, felis ante accumsan velit, nec molestie erat risus vel odio. In interdum maximus enim lobortis laoreet. Vivamus nisi odio, suscipit sit amet dui vel, consectetur mattis velit. Ut scelerisque sem eget tortor hendrerit, non bibendum enim rhoncus. Aenean id sem feugiat, eleifend leo nec, volutpat diam. Phasellus eget semper elit. Suspendisse vitae magna a ligula hendrerit malesuada. In magna velit, luctus at eros vitae, dignissim vehicula neque. In quis ex vel risus imperdiet feugiat eu vestibulum lorem. Nullam porttitor enim sed leo ornare, ac posuere tortor molestie. Fusce accumsan rutrum dictum. Aenean in erat neque. Maecenas rhoncus enim id nisl posuere, vel tristique neque vehicula. In efficitur, mauris non semper semper, justo mauris gravida ligula, ac bibendum sem lacus et diam. Nullam gravida sit amet diam et tristique.

Nulla urna justo, condimentum ut rhoncus vel, imperdiet sed mi. Aliquam venenatis, neque et facilisis placerat, dui felis lobortis diam, a pulvinar nibh velit fermentum tortor. Quisque nec commodo nibh, vitae varius elit. Cras sem dolor, fermentum ac dignissim eget, mattis in libero. Vivamus condimentum, diam et consectetur blandit, elit elit faucibus justo, condimentum rhoncus dui mi a ipsum. Aenean sit amet tellus leo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu sodales ipsum. Etiam blandit nibh sit amet nunc interdum viverra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed eget ligula nec metus vestibulum elementum. Nulla in dolor eget risus laoreet fermentum. Aenean vitae accumsan erat, ac fermentum libero. Fusce efficitur tincidunt nibh, vel fringilla orci consectetur vitae. Ut eget porttitor mi.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jagadish. This does work, but unfortunately, it doesn't work when there's enough content to cause the content section of the screen to scroll (which I didn't mention in my original post, so that's no fault of yours). So people know, the changes from my original code were to change `min-height` to `height` for the `container` class and to add `height: 1px;` to the `sidebar-and-content` class.

Comment: That's correct. It does not work in all normal, intended cases. However, I am using your provided answer as well as the other one to try and work out something that does work. Thank you.

Comment: Not bad, but not quite what I wanted (and again, apologies, as this is a lack of specificity on my part). Thanks a lot your help though. Basically, if there's enough content to cause scrolling, I want the regular page scrollbar to be used for scrolling the content, but when that happens, I don't want the sidebar to ever stretch below the bottom of the screen. The more I think about this, the more I'm thinking that maybe I'll have to use a `fixed` position container or something. Still thinking... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and it wasn't intentional at all. I made certain assumptions going in because I did not fully understand the problem, and it wasn't until you provided a good solution that I started testing more and realized there were other holes. I am sorry for wasting your time, but your answer was very helpful, and it started getting me thinking in the right direction. Unfortunately, that back and forth is probably necessary to help get to the right answer (which I haven't found yet).